# What does the notation $(\alpha^{+}\times \alpha^{+})\setminus \{(\alpha,\alpha)\}$ mean

Tags: notation, set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I would appreciate an explanation of what this means, where $\alpha\in \lambda$, and $\lambda$ is an infinite cardinal.

> > $(\alpha^{+}\times \alpha^{+})\setminus \{(\alpha,\alpha)\}$

I know $\alpha^{+}= \alpha\cup \{\alpha\}$

To put it in context, this is from part of a proof looking at an initial segment of $\lambda\times \lambda$, as stated: cut out by $(\alpha,\alpha)$, which is the the set $(\alpha^{+}\times \alpha^{+})\setminus \{(\alpha,\alpha)\}$.

It then says thus the initial segment has size at most $|\alpha^{+}|^2$. (Subsequently it says $\alpha$ is an ordinal with $\alpha\lt\lambda$.)

This is especially confusing since an initial segment of a set $S$, say $S_x$ is equal to $\{y\in S: y\lt x\}$, with a strict inequality. So how does $\alpha^{+}$ come into the picture?

Thanks

Comment: The successor operation is not just adding one ordinal. It is the next cardinal. Which usually means adding a lot of new ordinals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $(\alpha^{+}\times \alpha^{+})\setminus \{(\alpha,\alpha)\}$ just means exactly what it looks like: $\alpha^+\times \alpha^+$ is the Cartesian product $\{(x,y):x,y\in\alpha^+\}$.  In particular, one element of this Cartesian product is $(\alpha,\alpha)$, and so $(\alpha^{+}\times \alpha^{+})\setminus \{(\alpha,\alpha)\}$ is the set of all elements of $\alpha^+\times\alpha^+$ except for $(\alpha,\alpha)$.

As for calling this an initial segment, presumably $(\alpha^{+}\times \alpha^{+})\setminus \{(\alpha,\alpha)\}$ is the set of all elements of $\lambda\times \lambda$ which are less than $(\alpha,\alpha)$, for some ordering of $\lambda\times\lambda$ which would be clear from context.  The reason you would use $\alpha^+$ rather than $\alpha$ is that pairs like $(\alpha,\beta)$ or $(\beta,\alpha)$ for $\beta<\alpha$ are less than $(\alpha,\alpha)$.  If you just took $\alpha\times\alpha$, that set would not contain such pairs.

Comment: Dear Eric - I have a high regard for the way you carry yourself here and your generosity in helping others. Perhaps you would consider running for Moderator. With regards,

Comment: I'm honored by the suggestion, but I'm afraid I don't feel comfortable making such a commitment at this time.

Comment: Well in any case, I'm happy to give you a bounty.

Comment: Maybe I could please ask a follow-up (I'm reviewing). Is it correct to say, and would it be applicable here since $\alpha^{+}=\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$, then $\alpha^{+}\setminus\{\alpha\}=\alpha$? Otherwise, what does $(\alpha^{+}\times \alpha^{+})\setminus \{(\alpha,\alpha)\}$ look like without $(\alpha,\alpha)$? Thanks again,

Comment: Yes, $\alpha^+\setminus\{\alpha\}=\alpha$.